# How to "switch" project to subfolder?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've created a "root" folder inside my repo and moved there all my project files and folders. Now I would like to "switch" my local copy so that it will communicate with this folder and not whole repository. How to do this?

Now when I do Update I get not only my old files but it creates folder 'root' on my local copy and moves there whole copy of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the folder containing your working copy and select TortoiseSVN->Switch. Now just enter the new URL and update.

Comment: If you're doing this through TortoiseSVN, tick checkbox "Ignore ancestry"